# Regular Expression for manipulating multiple lists with headers

Tags: regex

Apologies for the poorly worded title, I'm having a hard time explaining what I'm trying to do without showing.

What I have is an absolutely massive list of tables with their associated columns in the following format:

```
TABLE_1
col_1
col_2
col_3
TABLE_2
col_1
col_2
col_3
TABLE_3
col_1
col_2
col_3
```

Note that the table names are in upper case and contain 0 or more underscores separating words, while the column names are lower case and contain 0 or more underscores separating words. What I need is the following format:

```
TABLE_1,col_1
TABLE_1,col_2
TABLE_1,col_3
TABLE_2,col_1
TABLE_2,col_2
TABLE_2,col_3
TABLE_3,col_1
TABLE_3,col_2
TABLE_3,col_3
```

I've been trying to do this through use of Sublime's Find and Replace with regular expressions but the closest I've gotten is this:

```
Find: ([A-Z].*)\n(^([a-z].*\n)+?)(?=[A-Z].*)
Replace: $1,$2
```

And I guess it almost works, or maybe not. The result looks like this:

```
TABLE_1,col_1
col_2
col_3
TABLE_2,col_1
col_2
col_3
TABLE_3,col_1
col_2
col_3
```

Regex may not even be the most practical way to solve this, I have no idea. But I am always trying to improve my regex abilities so I like to use problems like this as learning tools. Any pointers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't do it in one pass. But it can easily be done using a programming language.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I suspected this might be the case. Thank you for your response.

Comment: An advice: build your code to work line by line, test when a line is a table name.

Comment: It looks as though there are only 3 specific lines after a title, why not use `([A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*)\n([a-z][a-z0-9_]*)\n([a-z][a-z0-9_]*)\n([a-z][a-z0-9_]*)` to replace with `$1,$2\n$1,$3\n$1,$4`? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5rjsJO/1/).